# PHP: How to convert a multiple line string array into multiple array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have these lines stored in an array variable

```
pl_id=MDR_PLZ
ln_id=01N
dt_concluded=20191106115958796600
tx_seq_nr=122586
ts_seq_nr=1078
us_id=c0507387
```

Lines are more than displayed here, the point is .. I need to convert this one array into further arrays so that i can use this data. 
I tried to use explode to convert them into array but its no use. 
I tried converting all these lines to single line by using preg_replace, trim, so that after that i can save it to variable and then explode it to get array but it did not work ..

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean `$pl_id = 'MDR_PLZ'` like this?

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel. use `parse_ini_string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e4371c2f8982be5d2242b39a91a9096b6b98ac94)

```
print_r(array_map(function($v){return explode(PHP_EOL,$v);},$array));
```

Comment: this was awesome ... Thanks Roofe .. however I have no idea about PHP_EOL, i tried to understand it but failed .. if you can please kindly tell what it is .. that will be awesome .. Bless you Roofe

Comment: @Numan `PHP_EOL` stands for end of line, is a constant define in php `Core_d.php`.